# what hapenned to the data going from admin site in website. it is showing title object 1 instead of the data in it

Tags: django, database, web-applications, django-admin

[This is the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFu34.png)

[this is how i am connecting to database ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McV4e.png)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't show anything for models.py nor how you display it in HTML page; however, you must have done an error while displaying it in HTML page
if your Title model looks like this:

```
class Title(models.Model):
   text = models.Charfield(...)
```

then in HTML page:

```
   {{title.text}}
```

to get the actual text and just {{title}} won't give you what you want

the second guess is you didn't loop through them, as objects.all() returns a query set

```
{% for atitle in title %}
{{atitle.text}}
{% endfor %}
```

PLEASE BE MORE SPECIFIC NEXT TIME